# Windows Shadow Copy Backup and Restore

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, windows-home-server, windows-backup, shadow-copy

While answering [another question](https://superuser.com/questions/21390/time-machine-clone-for-windows) I had to wonder: Does Vista/7's Backup and Restore Center or Windows Home Server's automated backups include the Shadow Copies/Previous Versions of files?

It seems like it would be beneficial to include them but also costly for storage; does anyone know?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on what settings you use. If you choose to backup files, it will keep a copy of the files. If you choose to back up the entire computer, it will backup a copy of everything (files, settings, startup, etc).

Directly from [this page](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windows-vista/features/backup.aspx) on the Microsoft site regarding backup and restore center:

> Previously backed-up versions of files
>   use only a bare minimum of disk space.
>   If only a small part of a file changes
>   (such as one slide in a presentation),
>   only that portion gets tracked and
>   saved.

So yes, it does keep "versions" of the files, so to speak. You can change these settings according to how you want to save space as well. New backups can replace old ones, or build upon them. I suggest reading the above article for full information.

There are also small descriptions in the Backup and Restore Center:

[image]

Comment: So it will only keep the shadow copies when doing more-or-less a full partition backup?  Bleh

Comment: no, a file backup should as well.