# My computer won't start because it keeps restarting

Tags: boot, memory, crash, reboot

My computer suddenly doesn't start today (last used it last week).
When start it up, it was up for a few seconds, and then it restarts itself. This happens again and again. There is no beep at all.

Is this a likely problem with my power supply?

**Edit 1:**

It's the memory module that's causing the problem.

Booting the machine without any memory module is fine, no restarts happen.
But with the memory modules (2x 4GB) on, it just restarts again and again.
How can I test if it's a problem with motherboard or with the memory modules?

Comment: What does "it was up for a few seconds" mean? Did the OS boot? How far does it get?

Comment: It does not get far at all, it boots, and within a second, it restarts. Turned out it was either a faulty memory modules or faulty motherboard. Any idea how to find the cause? (i dont have another computer to chuck the mem modules in)

Comment: If you have any BIOS manual, then I guess it actually does list beep codes for bad memory. If true then, given the lack of such beeps, I'd say it's the motherboard. Testing with some other memory might easily prove me wrong though. (Or testing with just a single memory module, instead of both?)

Comment: Thanks Arjan for the insight. I tested it with one module, and no beep, it keeps restarting. Unfortunately I don't have any other memory module to test with. I think it's safe to say the problem is in the motherboard? Sigh, it will be painful to change the motherboard.

Comment: No BIOS manual then? And you did test with just the other memory module as well, right?

Comment: What do you mean by BIOS manual? If you mean the BIOS setup, i don't get that far. ANd i don't get any beep either.

Comment: Manual as in user manual, usage instructions. Type in your motherboard brand and type into Google to fetch some PDF version, to see if it's supposed to beep for bad memory. Without any memory you should still be able to get into the BIOS setup, I suppose. That might show some status of the power supply, fans, CPU, etcetera.

Comment: @Arjan Good news! I booted up the PC without any memory and it was running. Shut it down, and then plugged back all the memory modules, and it magically works again! 

I don't quite understand why, maybe I didn't plug them in properly before (when I was testing them too?)?

Didn't clean CMOS though, was about to do it.
Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Ok, please accept Richard's answer then, so folks know it's been solved. And after that off to [Time Machine for Windows](http://superuser.com/questions/7423/time-machine-for-windows)  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

> Is this a likely problem with my power supply?

That would be the obvious place to start. But could also be HDD (failing on a critical part of the boot code) or RAM (it takes a few seconds to fit the bad part).

Do a boot to go into the BIOS screens and check this also fails (eliminate HDD, and probably also the RAM), repeat after removing as much hardware as you can—reducing PSU load—to roughly check for PSU issues (this is not perfect, different power rails are dedicated, and if it is the CPU rail at fault you cannot easily reduce the load).

Comment: It's the memory module that's causing the problem.

Booting the machine without any memory module is fine, no restarts happen.
But with the memory modules (2x4GB) on, it just restarts again and again.
How can I test if it's a problem with motherboard or with the memory modules?

Comment: Good news! I booted up the PC without any memory and it was running. Shut it down, and then plugged back all the memory modules, and it magically works again! 

I don't quite understand why, maybe I didn't plug them in properly before (when I was testing them too?)?

Didn't clean CMOS though, was about to do it.
Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @lydonchandra: Good news indeed. I would strongly suggest running Memtest for a while to really check things out: http://www.memtest.org/ (Underlying fault could be some dust on a contact on similar, which a remove/insert moves out of the way.)

Comment: this problem keeps happening every time I want to boot up my PC after shutdown in the previous night. I'll run memtest the next time it boots up ok.