# System disk image backup

Tags: windows, backup, disk-image, windows-backup

Looking for poweruser suggestions for incremental system drive backup.

My system is a laptop, and main backup would be a disk at home.  Though would also like to "backup/restore on the road".

Preferably live, but I am able to do it from another installation.

Would like to view data a bit like in a version control system (when appropriate).

Currently Windows 7&8 (And might install a Linux distro).

In Windows 8, I am not able to follow the instructions for Windows 7.
In Windows 7, the native solution wants to back up more than my C-drive.

## Tuesday:

Think  there are a few solutions around.  I think the most important (After a proper image backup), is liveliness and then incrementalness.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you've rejected popular Internet backup solutions like [Mozy](http://mozy.com/), [Backblaze](http://www.backblaze.com/), [Carbonite](http://www.carbonite.com/), [SpiderOak](https://spideroak.com/), etc.  (If not, take a look!)

[CrashPlan](http://www.crashplan.com/) is a unique option because they let you back up to your own systems remotely, or those of friends (encrypted) - sort of your own personal Disaster Recovery solution.  It also reduces costs because you supply the storage.

Another less-known option is [JungleDisk](https://www.jungledisk.com/), which is neat because it uses [Amazon's Simple Storage Service](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/).  It starts at $0.093 to $0.12 per GB/month for storage (more data is cheaper), and data transfer in is free.  Data transfer out - recovery - is free up to 1 GB/month, then starts at $0.12 per GB after that.  Quite an inexpensive option, depending on the quantities you need.

Comment: The point is SYSTEM DRIVE - to be able to restore the entire C-drive so the OS can run.

Comment: I don't know much about backups, but I think image-backup is different from data-backup.

Comment: Also online backup is less interesting - if I lose my laptop, I want my data back, but i am not going to want the same image back..

Comment: Having a bit-by-bit copy of the system drive conflicts somewhat with your desire to see historical changes.  I think you're trying to solve two separate problems.  The only thing an image-style backup seems to get you here is recoverability if you break the OS install, and that's what a System Repair disc/USB drive is for. (http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/What-are-the-system-recovery-options-in-Windows-7)  Here are some more options: http://superuser.com/questions/7423/does-an-equivalent-of-time-machine-exist-for-windows

Comment: I am a developer, so i need to easily be able to get back an earlier state of my system (the ideal is VirtualBox).  The link is useful.

Answer (score -1):

For incremental backups, git is a useful tool.

Install git, you can use a live linux to do this, or install it with cygwin or something. Either way, find the directory that is the windows C:/ disk, this may be /host or /media/sfojeiosfjoefsjsoffehsifes(random stuff), then open in terminal, and link to the second disk using a remote mount, mount the remote on /host/.git or whatever is needed, then "git init" in /host (or whatever it is), "git add .", and "git commit . -m \"Today is blalbal\"". The \" are actual quotes to use.

http://pandorawiki.org/Mount_over_ssh

Comment: I have been thinking of incremental backup with GIT.  But for the system disk?

Comment: You'd need to script something to deal with the dates, but I can't help there. Git is highly reliable and that's why I'd use it for backups.

Comment: I think it is more than date ... security settings for example.  All suggestions I have seen is not backup software (Except possibly native Windows and Mac tools)

Comment: Digressions: There seems to be some backup solutions "on top of" Git.  Have you looked into some of those?