# Is there a time machine equivalent for windows that can back up network files?

Tags: windows, backup, time-machine

This question is similar to [Does an equivalent of Time Machine exist for Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/7423/does-an-equivalent-of-time-machine-exist-for-windows), with one difference:

The files I want to back up are on a network drive. The computer on that network drive is running Windows XP. I want to back up data on Windows 7.

How would I do so?

I'd like something similar to Mac OS X' time machine. So copy of data every hour, day, week. Then thinning out, data gets deleted automatically as time goes by. For example, the data for last day is kept as hourly snapshots. For last week, as daily snapshots every day. And for last month as weekly snapshots.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Windows 7 supports this by default through Windows Backup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC Altaro Backup softwares can do it. NOT freeware, but I use OOPS and BackupFS since the first beta version, and it saved me many times from wrong cut&paste or delete. It's not my only backup system, but it's the first one when I need to restore something.

Answer (score 5):

Have you looked in to Cobian Backup? It can be scheduled to run this kind of backup.

http://www.cobiansoft.com/cobianbackup.htm

Comment: a free ware. Good. Why you have only 1 reputation?

Comment: the downside is it doesn't delete old back up. When backups are older than a week I probably only need a good back up once every week rather than once every day.

Comment: @JimThio - acronis true image supports something like you want.

Comment: According to the features for the latest version, it does delete old backups: "The program can now automatically delete old files". I'd personally advise against using Acronis products, as i've always found them to be terrible.

Answer (score 1):

Use www.bos.co.il - especially useful for heterogeneous environments. You can even backup linux systems & virtual machines to Win & viceversa.

Answer (score 0):

I personally like using SyncBackPro from 2BrightSparks. It does a synchronization and can include network folders. We used this for a rolling 7 day backup of our network shared documents server. The initial backups took a bit, but after that, it does an incremental backup on just files that had changed.

http://www.2brightsparks.com/

Answer (score -1):

So the answer appears to be "No, there is nothing like Time Machine". Nothing that backs up the entire hard drive in addition to file backup. We all know there are a ton of file backup utilities for Windows,,but nothing as seamless as Time Machine which allows you to easily restore your entire Hard Disk drive, system and all, with just a couple of clicks. Just get a Mac!!