# Best Backup Tool for Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, backup

I would like to know what auto backup tool that you all use for Windows XP? I am using XP power tool now, but seems to me to be very slow and has problems with files with long filenames.

Comment: Doplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/886/what-backup-software-for-windows

Comment: Questions tagged **[windows][backup]** http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows+backup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "best" answer will depend on what you want to backup, and for how long.

Are you talking about long term, rolling backups of your entire hard drive?  Or are you talking about keeping a mirror of your My Documents folder?

I tend to do more quick-n-dirty backups to ensure I have a second copy of the "important" stuff.  I just use robocopy to mirror several specific directories to my NAS box.  For more serious/commercial use I'd consider purchasing something.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy

Answer (score 1):

I like [Mozy](http://mozy.com/) for personal backup. Its not that expensive and has the advantage that your backup is off-site and remotely accessible.

I also use [unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/) with a flash-drive for small backups (less than 10GB)

Answer (score 0):

I've used Acronis True Image in the past.  It's not free (nor cheap, for that matter) but it seemed like it was worked well.

Answer (score 0):

I use Genie Home Backup Manager (on Vista, but it works on XP.)  It's not free. http://www.genie-soft.com

They also have a new product called Genie Timeline that backs up as files are modified.  I tried it but didn't like it much - I prefer the traditional approach.