# Best Backup Versioning Control Software?

Tags: backup, version-control, windows-backup

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What backup software for Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/886/what-backup-software-for-windows)

Are there any backup software that have versioning control on Windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on what kind of backup you are looking for.

If you want to do **online** file backup with versioning, [Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com) is a great solution.  They have 50GB plan for $10/mn that supports unlimited versioning for every file in your Dropbox.  So you can revert to or download any previous version of the file.

Comment: I beleive you have to pay $14 per month if you want the versioning.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Mozy](https://mozy.com)