# Acronis True Image vs SyncBack for Windows 7 / Windows XP backups

Tags: backup, acronis-trueimage, syncback

I have been using Acronis True Image Home for some time and I am generally happy with it. I did a quick search here and found that here [Software to backup data and files on a Windows computer](https://superuser.com/questions/886/what-backup-software-for-windows) SyncBack beats True Image 18 to 3 (so to say).

I am using True Image to back up my two home PCs and I usualy do incrementing backups of all the disks (partion/disk mode) in the system.

Is there anyone who had experience with both True Image and SyncBack outline the main differences of these two systems. Would it be worthwhile to migrate from True Image to SyncBack.

Comment: You should consider Paragon Backup & Recovery. It's another "heavy-duty disk-backup" and I believe it's the best. It beats Acronis. Also it has free version.

Answer (score 4):

The advantage of SyncBack is that it has a free version, which is probably why it got so many votes.

Otherwise, SyncBack cannot be at all compared to Acronis.

SyncBack can only sync one **directory** at a time without incrementing backups and all the other features of Acronis. Acronis is a heavy-duty **disk**-backup.

For example, only Acronis can fully backup the system drive.

Answer (score 1):

If you are happy with Acronis, why change?

SyncBack is only file sync/backup software, it will not image or clone a hard drive like Acronis.

Answer (score 1):

When you do incremental or differential backups with SyncBack, it does *not* track whether files have been deleted. Therefore you may end up with excessive files when restoring a backup. Not so with True Image: It does track file deletions.

Another advantage of True Image over SyncBack: Restoring a series of incremental backups needs less user intervention. With SyncBack you have to restore each increment manually, step by step, which is error prone.

A disadvantage of TrueImage is that the backed up data is stored in a proprietary format. So, if something goes wrong, you rely on Acronis for help.