# What is the easiest way to backup a WinXP computer?

Tags: windows, backup

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What backup software for Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/886/what-backup-software-for-windows)

I'm looking at setting up a backup for a non-technical friend, using an external HDD.

What is the best way to ensure that their data is backed up?  I can't count on them to remember to run something periodically, so I'm not sure if synchtoy is a viable option.

What other options are there for simple, idiot-proof backups?

Comment: This is not the same as the dupe - that's asking for the most advanced backup, I need a simple backup for a non-technial user - two different questions with hopefully different answers.

Comment: The answers will be the same. This is also not the first time this question has been asked. Slightly changing the criteria is not going to chance the software recommendation and definitely doesn't make it any less of a dupe.

Answer (score 1):

Windows XP comes with an intern backup solution. called NTBackup.exe.
I am using this for years to backup my parents system.

[Here](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/using/setup/learnmore/bott_03july14.mspx) is a nice howto on using it. By folowing these instructions, you will be able to backup your system nice and clean. You also can set a shedule to run the job automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using [Deltacopy](http://www.aboutmyip.com/AboutMyXApp/DeltaCopy.jsp) for daily unattended backups of the XP My Documents folder to a usb thumb drive. The new program Syncrify by the same outfit might be easier to set up (haven't tried it). Are the computer and external hard drive always running?