# Local backup software?

Tags: windows-xp, backup

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What backup software for Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/886/what-backup-software-for-windows)

I work in a corporate environment running Windows XP and I have access to a network drive. The problem is the network is down every now and then (3 to 6 months). So I've been experimenting with backing up my files on the network drive onto my hard drive using SyncToy. However, SyncToy isn't a great back up option as it does not store multiple revisions/versions of the file by date. Is there a free desktop backup alternative that can make backups and store multiple versions of the files (by date, say)?

Comment: Multiple. What OS?

Comment: We run Windows XP.

Comment: Please define Corporate environment - is it a small business of 5-10 users?  Is it a large business of 1000+ users?  Have you considered using Offline Files and Volume Shadow Copy?

Comment: Size doesn't matter I don't think. We just have a network drive. Does Offline files of VSC (available only in Vista and Win7?) keep multiple copies of the files?

Answer (score 1):

[SyncBackSE](http://www.2brightsparks.com/syncback/sbse.html) is a great solution for what you are looking to do, but it costs $30.