# Free software for backing up an attached network drive

Tags: windows-7, backup, nas, incremental-backup

My wireless router comes with a USB connector which allows me to plug an external hard drive in and it'll act as a Network Attached Storage. The problem is that I want to backup this hard-drive to the external drive of another computer so that if the NAS drive fails, I don't lose everything.

However, Windows 7 Backup refuses to include the NAS as a location to backup. I can't fool it by mapping it to a drive letter either. Google presents lots of pages on how to backup files to a NAS, but not the other way around.

Can anyone advise me on free software which can do incremental backups of a NAS drive to an external drive attached the computer it is running on? I'm aware of [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/886/what-backup-software-for-windows) but the top answers have one or more of the following issues:

1. They aren't free.
2. The free version cannot backup a NAS.
3. They cannot do incremental backups.
4. They're just a script and therefore have limited other functionality (eg. disk space management, scheduling, compression, etc.etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment, the (free) backup solution I recommend to people is [Cobian Backup](http://www.educ.umu.se/~cobian/cobianbackup.htm).

It should hopefully meet your needs.

edit -

it is on that list on the other question. What did you find wrong with it?

Comment: I didn't see anything on the website or documentation detailing backing up a NAS to a local disk - however it sounds like I may have overlooked it. Will look again, thanks.

Comment: @Richard - it can do pretty much anything - ftp/windows shares and more, so you can backup to a NAS anyway you want! //nasname, map to a drive or more...

Answer (score 0):

Snapshot http://www.drivesnapshot.de is my favorite program to do what you are asking for, but it is not free.  I use it all the time, and it runs at about $50

I think crashplan may be able to do what you are looking for - but I haven't tried them. http://b3.crashplan.com/consumer/crashplan.html

The link to do what you are looking to do with crashplan is http://support.crashplan.com/doku.php/recipe/back_up_windows_mapped_drives