# Which backup software for me?

Tags: windows-7, backup

Must be free (prerably also for commercial use, but I guess I can live without that; home has priority over work; it's just that I like to use the same tools at both if I can)

I don't need encrustation, Zip or other packing or incremental backuos. I don't need backup of common windows directories, like My Documents, or programs like Outlook.

I do need scheduling, with the ability to name the back up directories (e.g., daily backup - Mon/Tue... or Week 1, 2, 3 .. or Month - Jan/Feb...)

It would be nice to be able to exclude certain file types, which I define.

Copying of locked/open files is nice bonus.

---

[Update]  For US $19.95, https://www.bvckup2.com/ seems prefect (`"Select a pair of folders and Bvckup 2 will make sure that one stays an exact copy of the other. It is light, uncomplicated and really well designed. It is also incredibly fast."`), and I can get the naming that I want with this solution https://bvckup2.com/support/forum/topic/225 (or https://www.bvckup2.com/support/forum/topic/487).

I hope that this helps someone who is looking for something similar.

Comment: Have you looked through the questions you got as possible duplicates when you wrote this one? Is there anything you don't want from the possible solutions there?

Comment: Have a look through - http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/backup.  Plenty of solutions outlined.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/886/what-backup-software-for-windows

Comment: "Have you looked through the questions you got as possible duplicates when you wrote this one? Is there anything you don't want from the possible solutions there?"  ... Yes, but +1 for taking teh time to reply. Thanks

Comment: 'Plenty of solutions outlined." yes, I know how to search. None met my needs, but +1 for taking the time to reply.

Comment: "closed as subjective and argumentative by ChrisF, techie007, DMA57361" - on what grounds?  I knwo enough not to ask "what is the best backup program" - and would be interested in the reply anyway.  Sure the qualifier "for me" and a list of requirements makes it neither subjective nor argumentative ?  Or could one of you explain why you thought it so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a nice list of free backup programs that might suit your needs...

http://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-backup-program

Answer (score 1):

I have personally used Genie Timeline in the past.

It is free and easy to use. The interface is intuitive and rather modern looking.

There is a link:

http://www.genie9.com/free_products/free_timeline.aspx

Comment: But no mention of whether it meets my needs. +1 anyway, why not?