# What is a trustworthy backup/recovery scheme for Windows Vista?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, backup, hard-drive-recovery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Software to backup data and files on a Windows computer](https://superuser.com/questions/886/software-to-backup-data-and-files-on-a-windows-computer)

The title is the question:  How can one implement a backup/recovery scheme on Windows Vista (laptop) that is reliable and doesn't simply involve rebuilding the installation from scratch?  This would be either after a physical drive crash or some sort of software SNAFU that tanks the installed image.

(Note I don't ask for software recommendations since that is apparently against the rules.)

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/athome/setup/backupdata.aspx#fbid=-XP6BjuVuo1

Comment: My main way of backing up a computer, use a external drive and a live OS like gparted, create a entire backup of the drive/partition monthly that your OS is on.

Comment: ... using something like **dd** (adding to what user88311 said).

Comment: @akira -- I don't know about their "cloud" option, but regular "Windows Backup and Restore" does not backup your system, it only backs up your data.

Comment: So in other words you want software to install and just afk backup your computer for you, not 5 clicks of a button and making a live OS flash drive or disc.

Comment: @DanielRHicks: no, it backups either a set of files .. or (and thats called a "system image") the system. either incrementally or full. http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/System-Restore-frequently-asked-questions and http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Back-up-your-programs-system-settings-and-files

Comment: @akira -- You are gravely mistaken.  The "full backup" is not a restorable image.  And "System Restore" restores nothing other than some registry items and a few file links.

Comment: @DanielRHicks: "Windows Complete PC Backup creates a backup image, which contains copies of your programs, system settings, and files". it is more sophisticated in windows7. but it stores _everything_. the amount of sophistication increases with the version of windows (home -> ultimate) you bought. also read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backup_and_Restore

Comment: @akira - "Windows Complete PC Backup" is not installed on Vista Home Premium, which is what comes (er, came) on the vast majority of laptops.  And I've never seen it for sale separately.

Comment: The question still isn't really a good fit here. It is asking for a protracted discussion. As you can see from these comments.

Comment: It's asking for an answer.  How do I get that?

Comment: @DanielRHicks: "Manual image-based full system backup (including incremental backup) can be done on local or removable media in Windows 7 Home Premium."

Comment: This still seems like the only possible answers would be software suggestions.

Comment: @Ramhound: since it is a software problem the only answers will be software related :) its just a trick question into "tell be what else to buy since i dont trust windows-internals".

Comment: @akira -- Find the same statement for Vista.